# How to Execute Core Show channels Command in java and also grep Channels in it

Tags: java, process, grep, asterisk

I would like a help from u all .I am using java and i want to execute the a command that is use to get the channels details in asterisk. the system is linux based.
I want to execute command "core show channels" at the same time  want to grep channels also

Following is the command and the output when fire normally in console.

```
   asterisk -vvvvvrx 'core show channels' | grep channels
```

and the output is 
2 active channels

I am trying to use following code in java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class ProcessBuilderExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
  String[] commands = new String[]{"asterisk","-rx","core show channels","| grep 'channels'"};
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
    p.waitFor();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   String line = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
}
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}
```

but it is not showing me the correct output pls help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

`String[] commands = new String[]{"asterisk","-rx","core show channels","| grep 'channels'"};`

to:

```
String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "asterisk -rx 'core show channels' | grep 'channels'"};
```

Reason:

Your vertical bar will be interpreted as "\|"(i.e. literally "|" instead of a pipe"), if we instead invoke a shell command(/bin/sh) and put the whole command as its argument, vertical bar will be correctly interpreted.

Comment: sorry it just not returning me any thing

Comment: Have you tried command directly in the shell: `asterisk -rx core show channels | grep 'channels'` and `/bin/sh -c "asterisk -rx core show channels | grep 'channels'"`?

Comment: Thank You. Solution was correct only thing is String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "asterisk -rx core show channels | grep channels"}; we dont need the single quote that is surrounded to channels and we need the single quote on the command that is 'core show channels'

Comment: Correct One is:String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "asterisk -rx 'core show channels' | grep channels"};

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting mixed up between command arguments and piping. When you say `cmda | cmdb` it essentialy means run `cmda` and pass its output as an input of `cmdb` whereas your code passes the string "| cmdb" as an argument of `cmda`

There are several ways you can do to fix your code, but I think the most straight forward way is to take away the last grep argument:

```
String[] commands = new String[]{"asterisk","-rx","core show channels"};
```

Then when you're looping the result, just use the `contains()` method from String class to check if it contain the string *channels*

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if(line.contains("channels")  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: the code u provided works but i want to grep the result. the code will show all the output. but i need to search a particular field from  that because of which i want to use grep command

Comment: The code will not show all the output, only lines that contain the string "channels". I'm assuming this is what you're after? Of course if you insist on piping, you can achieve that by creating 2 Process objects, read the ouput from process 1 and pass it as an input to process two

Comment: no the code u provided doesnt give me the lines that contain the string channels. if would have given i would have got my answer. besides this the code give me whole output.that i get when i run this command